# how to add joomla site header in my custom php file without using ready made plugin or module?

Tags: php, joomla

I have been develope one site in joomla framework. Now my trouble is that client want one custom page in this site. so, please guide me how to i setup theme interface in this custom page?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not my favorite solution, instead of including Joomla in your script, you can put your script inside an article with an extension that can read your code, like [DirectPHP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/4470?qh=YTozOntpOjA7czozOiJwaHAiO2k6MTtzOjU6InBocCdzIjtpOjI7czo0OiJwaHAnIjt9) and others.

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like error.php which is really a mini application that renders a single page. You can see in the core how elements of the emplae are used and you can evn pull in modules and so on.